# am getting this error, can any one help? "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: php, mysql

what i am trying to do is registering a new student to my database, hence storing it to the table student.
my php code, i dont know where is the error, though am not a pro in php language. here is all my php codes. 
getting this error while trying to add records.

```
public function form(){
    $html = new Html();

    $html->div("row");
    $html->alert("message","Add New Student");

    $html->form("processstudent.php");

    $html->table("table table-bordered", "width:500px; margin:0 auto;");

    $html->input("", "hidden", "studentid", "");

    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Firstname"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "firstname", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();

    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Lastname"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "lastname", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Emailaddress"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "emailaddress", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Password"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "password", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Dateofbirth"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "date", "dateofbirth", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Contact Number"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "contactnumber", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Address"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "address", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Gender"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->input("form-control", "text", "gender", null); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Program"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->selectprogram(); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Cohort"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->selectcohort(); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();
    $html->column(); echo "Department"; $html->closecolumn();
    $html->column(); $html->selectdepartment(); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();


    $html->row();

    $html->column(); $html->closecolumn(); $html->column(); $html->input("btn btn-primary", "submit", "addstudent", "Add"); $html->closecolumn();
    $html->closerow();

    $html->closetable();

    $html->closeform();
    $html->closediv();
}


///////// Add Student 

public function add(){
    $mysql = new Mysql();
    $query = "insert into student VALUES ('','$this->firstname','$this->lastname','$this->emailaddress','$this->password','$this->dateofbirth','$this->contactnumber','$this->address','$this->gender','$this->cohort','$this->program','$this->department'); ";

    $mysql->execute($query);
    if($mysql->result)
        $mysql->successMessage ("Successfully inserted data");
}





}



?>
```

Comment: It means that you're trying to insert into a specific number of columns and that the number of inserted values do not match the column count of the table. *Count* the number of columns in your table then *count* the number of items you're trying to insert. Make sure those counts *match*.

Comment: @won-jun-bae error mentioned in title

Answer (score 3):

It means you're trying to insert an incorrect number of values in relation to the number of columns in the database.

It's better for readability to do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ($value1,$value2,$value3)
```

then you'll know your columns and values match properly.